# AWS Lambda Layer Using Another Layer

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, layer, aws-sam

I've got a nodejs AWS Lambda Layer (lets call it `dbUtil`) with some low level database access code (stuff like opening connections, executing prepared statements, etc.).

Now I want to create another layer (let's call it `modelUtil`) with higher level, data model-specific code (stuff like data transfer objects, and model-specific transformations).

I would very much like to be able to leverage the code in the `dbUtil` layer within the higher-level `modelUtil` layer, while still being able to import `dbUtil` into a lambda function independently.

Importing the layer to a *lambda* function is easy as SAM plops the layer code into `/opt/nodejs/`. But as far as I know, nothing analogous exists for layers; AWS doesn't give you the ability to import a layer into *another* layer in the same way. Additionally, each layer is self-contained, so I couldn't have the layer just put `const dbUtil = require('./dbUtil')` in the `modelUtil.js` file, unless they were in the same directory when I built the layer, and thus, forcing them to *be* the same layer.

Is there a way I can have a dependency from one layer (`modelUtil`) on another layer (`dbUtil`) while still allowing them to be treated as independent layers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this on Lambda and I can testify that **a Layer can import functions and dependencies from another Layer**. Even the merge order does not matter.

For your case, for `modelUtil` Layer to **import functions** from `dbUtil` Layer:
(Inside `modelUtil`)
`const func1 = require('/opt/<the location of func1 in dbUtil>')`

For `modelUtil` Layer to import **npm dependencies** from `dbUtil` Layer:
(Inside `modelUtil`)
`const dependency = require(dependency)`

It is as simple as that!